# MySql JOIN for multiple tables with "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have two Tables timetable and subjects_teacher

### Timetable

```
id     student_teacher_id   Period
1      1                     8:00
2      2                     9:00
3      3,4                   10:00
4      1,5                   11:00
5      6                     12:00
```

### Student_Teacher

```
id     Sub_name     student_id     teacher_id
1        ENG             1             1
2        SO              2             2
3        Sc              3             3
4        Ma              4             4
5        Lang-1          5             5
6        Lang-2          6             6
```

Now I want to get the all periods related to teacher_id = 1 USING JOIN LIKE

```
SELECT t.period FROM timetable t
JOIN student_table st ON t.student_teacher_id IN (st.id)
WHERE st.teacher_id = 1
```

Is it correct? Please anyone give me best way to get list...

Comment: Whay do you have something like student_teacher_id. This is an anomaly. You should consider reworking the structure of your table(s).
Also, what doess student_table look like?

Comment: yes, very messy that structure

Comment: Please normalize your data properly. THen most of your problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said

> YOU MUST RESTRUCTURE(NORMALIZE) YOUR DATABASE

your query should be like this

```
SELECT t.period FROM Student_Teacher st
LEFT JOIN Timetable t ON st.id IN (t.student_teacher_id )
WHERE st.teacher_id = 1
```